# See list of history through react-router props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js

I currently have a button that onClicks to `history.goBack` but I want it to direct the user to another path if there isn't a previous page (in the case the user visits the page directly by typing in the URL in the URL bar instead of clicking within the site to get there). When I checked out `this.props.history` there isn't an object containing the history of pages visited or a boolean that tells me if there is a page for `history.goBack` to work on. How do I check that? Looking at the docs for [history](https://github.com/mjackson/history) library, there is suppose to be an `entries` property but this somehow didn't make it into react-router.

Answer (score 0):

You can use go() property to move further back.
Eg. go(-1) will be equivalent of goBack() and go(1) will be equivalent of goForward().
I don't think there is a way to list all the paths on the stack, but you could allways implement history that you can push to and control.